# Auto select when selected in database

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following code in my Rails app:

```
<h2>Budget (optional)</h2>
  <select id="trip_currency" name="trip[currency]">
    <option value="" disabled="disabled">Please select</option>
    <option value="EUR">Euro - EUR</option>
    <option value="USD">United States Dollars - USD</option>
    <option value="GBP">United Kingdom Pounds - GBP</option>
    <option value="CAD">Canada Dollars - CAD</option>
  </select>
```

When a user selects **USD**, it is stored in my database. Then when he edits the page, it always go back to the first option value **EUR**.

How do I write in Rails to have **USD** selected according to database? I have previous code for country selects using:

```
<%= country_select("user", "location", [], :include_blank => true, :option_value => "#{params[:location]} selected") %>
```

I'm not sure how to re-implement the above on my budget because the options in budget are expanded to individual option.

Please advise. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you use the following methodology in general:

1) In your view:

```
<%= your_form_variable.select(:civility,  Your_model::CURRENCIES, {:include_blank => 'SPlease select'}) %>
```

2) in your model:

```
CURRENCIES = [["EUR", "Euro - EUR"], [...]]
```

Comment: Thanks. What is the [...] I should put in my model? Also, this is for Rails 3 right? I am using Rails 2.3.8.

Comment: Yes for rails 3, [...] means you can add whatever currency you want, put an array for each one.

Comment: Thanks. I noticed that hardcoding like I did doesn't do it right. Should do it Rails way as you did, then it works.